# Redirect/block WordPress URLs with the /?p=x structure. Eg. site.com/?p=2

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect

I'm building a site with hashed permalinks so I can email a `test.com/aedoiu2348791lkd` style URL to a client. It's to provide a level of privacy without the need to log in or dick around with passwords.

Unfortunately, WordPress redirects any URL with the `?p=x` url structure:

*so* `mysite.com/?p=2` *redirects to* `mysite.com/about`

---

Obviously, the hashed URL is pretty useless when someone can run through `/?p=xx` and see every post and page I've ever made.

Is there a way to stop WordPress from redirecting this type of link and either throwing a 404 or redirecting to the homepage?

I only want the page to be accessible from the "proper" `mysite.com/asdfghj-page` style of URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution ...sort of
Added to top of .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /?p=(\d*)
RewriteRule ^$ *? [R=404,L]
</IfModule>
```

I don't really get it... but this works.
Ideally it would redirect to the wordpress 404 page, however.